# I cant edit php files with Brackets from FileZilla on KUbuntu

Tags: kubuntu, adobe-brackets

I click edit then download the .php/.css file  to my computer then Brackets open WITHOUT THE FILE.Brackets opens with index.html which is about brackets.How to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume you are trying to point Brackets to Filezilla because the files are located on a remote server. Is that correct?

Comment: @Gordster Can you look at my question again because I  completely editted

Comment: @Gordster Can you look at my question again because I completely editted –

Comment: Seems as though you have to open the files with brackets. You should be able to right click the file and then choose to open it with brackets.